# Chrome console not returning values

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console

I've been using Chrome everyday and for some reason today when I open up the console to retrieve values while debugging, nothing is returned. If I set a breakpoint and hover over a variable it works fine, but typing it in doesn't return anything. Is it possible that there is some sort of setting I accidentally messed with? I have no idea what went wrong overnight :(

[image: No value returned]

The value definitely exists, I am able to return it using the same method in both IE and FF.

Comment: may be reboot chrome?

Comment: do you have a filter set (bottom right, `All`, `Errors`, `Warnings`,...)?

Comment: Tried that... I also reinstalled Chrome and rebooted my machine but still no luck.

Comment: alternatively, is there blocking code running in the browser (or a currently active breakpoint)?

Comment: ...YES. No idea how I didn't catch that - it was set to Errors :( I'm ashamed.

Comment: But You're wiser now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Be sure that you don't have a filter set in the console

[image: filters in chrome dev tools]

Answer (score 0):

In my case the chrome virtual machine was broken, try the same thing on a new tab of your browser.